# PyCUDA: Querying Device Status (Memory specifically)

Tags: python, cuda, device-driver, gpgpu, pycuda

PyCUDA's documentation mentions [Driver Interface](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html) calls in passing, but I'm a bit think and can't see how to get information such as 'SHARED_SIZE_BYTES' out of my code.

Can anyone point me to any examples of querying the device in this way?

Is it possible to / How do I check the device state (eg between malloc/memcpy and kernel launch) to implement some machine-dynamic operations? (I want to be able to deal with devices that support multiple kernels in a 'friendly' way.

Comment: Are you asking about the attribute fields given in pycuda.driver.function_attribute ? Those are not device attributes, they are per compiled function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just for anyone else coming across this, spending half an hour with the [CUDA API](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0_rc2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Reference_Manual.pdf) in one hand, and the [PyCUDA documentation](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#devices-and-contexts) in another does wonders. Its much simpler than my initial experiments indicated.

**Runtime Kernel Info**

*Incoming lazy lazy code*

```
...
kernel=mod.get_function("foo")
meminfo(kernel)
...
def meminfo(kernel):
    shared=kernel.shared_size_bytes
    regs=kernel.num_regs
    local=kernel.local_size_bytes
    const=kernel.const_size_bytes
    mbpt=kernel.max_threads_per_block
    print("=MEM=\nLocal:%d,\nShared:%d,\nRegisters:%d,\nConst:%d,\nMax Threads/B:%d" % (local,shared,regs,const,mbpt))
```

*Example Output*

```
=MEM=
Local:24,
Shared:64,
Registers:18,
Const:0,
Max Threads/B:512
```

**Static Device Info**

*Incoming lazy lazy code*

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda

(free,total)=cuda.mem_get_info()
print("Global memory occupancy:%f%% free"%(free*100/total))

for devicenum in range(cuda.Device.count()):
    device=cuda.Device(devicenum)
    attrs=device.get_attributes()

    #Beyond this point is just pretty printing
    print("\n===Attributes for device %d"%devicenum)
    for (key,value) in attrs.iteritems():
        print("%s:%s"%(str(key),str(value)))
```

*Example Output*

```
Global memory occupancy:70.000000% free

===Attributes for device 0
MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK:512
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X:512
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y:512
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z:64
MAX_GRID_DIM_X:65535
MAX_GRID_DIM_Y:65535
MAX_GRID_DIM_Z:1
MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK:16384
TOTAL_CONSTANT_MEMORY:65536
WARP_SIZE:32
MAX_PITCH:2147483647
MAX_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK:8192
CLOCK_RATE:1500000
TEXTURE_ALIGNMENT:256
GPU_OVERLAP:1
MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT:14
KERNEL_EXEC_TIMEOUT:1
INTEGRATED:0
CAN_MAP_HOST_MEMORY:1
COMPUTE_MODE:DEFAULT
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_WIDTH:8192
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_WIDTH:65536
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_HEIGHT:32768
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH:2048
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT:2048
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH:2048
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_WIDTH:8192
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_HEIGHT:8192
MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_NUMSLICES:512
SURFACE_ALIGNMENT:256
CONCURRENT_KERNELS:0
ECC_ENABLED:0
PCI_BUS_ID:1
PCI_DEVICE_ID:0
TCC_DRIVER:0
```

Comment: That is a device query output, but in your original question you were asking about code properties. Which are you actually interested in?